# Resultset or RowMapper? which one best in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring

- **ResultSet**

A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

- **RowMapper**

Like ResultSetExtractor, we can use RowMapper interface to fetch the records from the database using query() method of JdbcTemplate class. In the execute of we need to pass the instance of RowMapper now.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Both have their uses and neither is always better than the other.  But this is a bit too opinion based...

Comment: It depends on what's your need. Internally RowMapper uses ResultSet. RowMapper is kinda my favorite because it makes my code simple and readable.

Comment: @D3X - please simply mark as a possible duplicate. No need to shout :-)

Comment: @BrianAgnew- i am sorry, actually i just read the same question a few mins back, so just placed a comment on the same, intention was not so.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`RowMapper` is a higher level concept. You don't have to look after iterating across the `ResultSet` yourself. Rather, the framework iterates and calls you for each entry. You simply return an object built from each row, and the framework combines these into a collection.

As such, I would use the higher level concept and let the framework do the tedious drudgery of iterating and combining into a collection. `RowMapper` allows you to focus on the business of mapping rows to objects.